# Supervisor cancels PhD students' salary when he feels productivity is low; what to do?

Tags: phd, advisor, funding

My friend's PhD supervisor (CS in EU) is severe to the point of cancelling a month of salary when he feels productivity rates are not met by his students. Given that the students are just starting (4 months now), how should they deal with this situation? Should they complain about salary, and if yes, to whom?

Comment: At my university (somewhere in Australia), the funding of students is detached from their supervisor for this reason.  A supervisor should never ever hold such power or leverage over his/her students.  This may be different in other countries.

Comment: From what little I know of the EU, it is hard to imagine this could occur? Clearly head to the appropriate office...

Comment: Why would any student stay with this professor? Find the door. Run in that direction. Fast.

Comment: he actually crossed a red line doing that.

Comment: To get an accurate answer you should probably specify the country, and the nature of the PhD student's employment contracts or funding agreements.

Comment: Not paying people for work done is certainly illegal - possibly to the point of going to jail - in every developed country.  Moreover, higher-ups at the university could be liable - possibly to the point of going to jail.  The head of the department and the human resources office at the university will certainly want to know about this.  If they don't listen, the government department in charge of enforcing labor laws will want to know.

Comment: I think it is really necessary to specify at least the country in order to get specific advice. Laws and regulations vary widely within the European Union.

Comment: There's basically nothing they can do unless they plan on switching advisors, if they are your funding source they can just decide to stop paying you. You can always leave or go to another advisor but there's really no consequence for bad behavior on their part. There's too much exploitable labor in academia, mostly revolving around people from poor countries.

Comment: @JochenGlueck I'm not a lawyer but I'm pretty sure withholding salary violates EU legislation. The country shouldn't matter. What matters is if the "salary" is actually salary, i.e., if OP's "friend" is actually an employee.

Comment: @Roland: That was my first thought, too; but I it seems to be difficult to find concrete information. One important point is that many EU legal acts are [directives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_(European_Union)), which have to be implemented in national law by each member country on its own. Thus, the details of the legislation might vary considerably by country. (But admittedly, I'm not sure to which extent this applies to the OP's situation.)

Comment: The country would be very interesting. For the EU countries I'm familiar with, I find this story hard to believe. The processes are normally set up in a way that a supervisor cannot do something like that.

Comment: believe it or not it's Norway

Comment: @Sam Has the supervisor *actually cancelled salaries* or *threatened to do so*? I think most of the surprise is coming from assuming your language to indicate that pay for some period worked was actually withdrawn/not paid, but it could be also read as a threat to not pay.

Comment: threatened to do

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they should complain. To whom is difficult to answer without being closer to the situation; I would have some idea in my US organization but not about what the organization is like at your friend's university.

For me, step one would probably have been with the office folk in my grad program. They'd be acutely aware that this isn't normal and have helpful suggestions for where to escalate next.

Next up might be the chair of the graduate program, and then the chair of the department if this is a different person. After that would be human resources/payroll administrators; they're the ones that will eventually have to correct any wrongly withheld funds, but that shouldn't be the first point of contact.

An alternative track would be through an ombudsperson whose office is meant to mediate disputes between students and university employees. I think starting locally is better, though.

One could also consult a lawyer at some point to find out what their legal standing is, and it is very much your right to consult with a lawyer, though I'd caution that once lawyers are involved everyone at the university may quickly become less helpful. This is not necessarily because they *want to be* less helpful, but because of direction from their own higher ups and the university itself to clear everything through legal once lawyers start moving in. IMO this is painful and unfortunately not worth the value of a month of graduate school salary; others might feel the principle is worth it, but it's probably not a good career move even if the case would be totally justified.

---

This is a serious enough transgression that I think it's probably not a recoverable situation with the advisor. Maybe, in some unusual circumstance, it could be forgiven as a very misguided motivational strategy from someone new to how things work. I think that's almost certainly an overly charitable assessment.

I'd recommend moving to a new advisor as soon as possible, and leaving the university as soon as possible if contacting the people on some rough equivalent of my list is not fruitful. Denying salary for lack of productivity is never okay. If progress is truly not satisfactory, there will be better official channels with proper protections in place for review.

Your friend is just starting out. It will become harder and harder to move on in the future: the sunk costs will be higher and potential avenues for abuse less blatant. A lot of the assessment of a PhD student's progress is based on the expressed opinions of their advisor. Does your friend want someone who would threaten to withhold their paycheck to be the person helping them make decisions about authorship? Deciding when and whether they graduate? Recommending them for future academic positions/jobs? Giving them academic, career, and personal advice?

Comment: Would this mean the end of the PhD for them if the advisor comes to know about the complaint ?

Comment: @Sam Hopefully the student can move to another advisor in the program. I don't see how the advisor can not be made aware of the complaint: the complaint is that they've done something unethical and threatened or done something (I presume, not knowing the details or jurisdiction) illegal. If the student does not act now, I can't imagine things getting much better for them. If an advisor will do this, what else will they do?

Comment: @Sam - Are you asking if someone should accept enslavement (because that's what this amounts to) for a PhD that they might never get to finish?  As an aside, if immigration is involved, most countries have laws protecting the rights of victims to remain in the country when they expose wrongdoing.  They're usually meant for human trafficking cases, but...